# Java 8 ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to use ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString() to get the current time. It works well, but seems to cut off seconds / milliseconds when they are right on a rollover (00.000Z), or so it appears. Normally it wouldn't matter, but I am writing the data to ElasticSearch, which has a strict mapping for the date I am passing (acquired time).

I maybe am off in what I am thinking is happening, but want to try to make sure I can always provide a date/time with seconds and milliseconds.

Basic Code snippet (first pass was to add milliseconds, but appears seconds could also possibly be left out):

```
def utcDate = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
def utcDateStr = utcDate.toString()
utcDateStr = utcDateStr.contains(".") ? utcDateStr
        : utcDateStr.replace("Z","").concat(".000Z")
```

Want it to be in the format below, which it almost always is:

```
2016-06-16T05:43:07.624Z
```

Comment: It would be clearer if you'd say that calling `toString()` cuts off the seconds / milliseconds... otherwise it sounds like `now()` itself is broken.

Comment: Ahh, good point @JonSkeet. You are correct, I will edit / fix the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, it sounds like you really want an `Instant` rather than a `ZonedDateTime` - that takes the time zone part out of the picture entirely. But either way, just use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to format the value however you want.

It sounds like you want something like (in Java; adjust to Groovy appropriately):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US)
    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Instant now = Instant.now();
String text = formatter.format(now); 
System.out.println(text);
```

That will still output the milliseconds value even if it's 0.

(If you really want to use `ZonedDateTime`, you can do so with the same formatter. But conceptually, what I think you're trying to represent is just an instant in time, and `Instant` is the better fit for that.)

Comment: Any particular reason you chose `uuuu` over the more common `yyyy`?

Comment: @shmosel: Initially, because `yyyy` didn't work. `uuuu` didn't either, due to me not setting the time zone... but anyway, `yyyy` is year-of-era, which means "1905" is actually ambiguous between 1905AD and 1905BC. Unlikely to be an issue, but just "year" is slightly cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the formatter route, you can build one like so:

```
DateTimeFormatter ES_ISO8601_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .append(
                    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                            .parseCaseInsensitive()
                            .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
                            .appendLiteral('T')
                            .append(
                                    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
                                            .appendLiteral(':')
                                            .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
                                            .appendLiteral(':')
                                            .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
                                            .appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 3, 9, true)
                                            .toFormatter()
                            )
                            .toFormatter()
            )
            .appendOffsetId()
            .toFormatter();
```

(That's cobbled together from the code in the DateTimeFormatter class in Java 8)

The change is basically giving

```
                                        .appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 3, 9, true)
```

a min width of 3, instead of 0 in the original ISO formatter